# Using count in mysql join

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have been trying to write a sql query to get some stats from bugzilla. Here is the query

```
select bugs.bug_id AS bug_id, 
       COUNT(map_pingpong.bug_when) AS re_open, 
       MAX(map_closetime.bug_when) AS closed_date 
  from bugs 
         LEFT JOIN bugs_activity AS map_pingpong 
                 ON ((map_pingpong.bug_id = bugs.bug_id 
                        and map_pingpong.fieldid=15)) 
         LEFT JOIN bugs_activity AS map_closetime 
                 ON ((bugs.bug_id = map_closetime.bug_id 
                        and map_closetime.fieldid=8 
                        and bugs.bug_status = 'CLOSED' )) 
 where (bugs.assigned_to = 480) 
 GROUP BY bugs.bug_id 
 ORDER BY bug_id;
```

So, the query supposed to return two things

1) Count of an event happening
2) Date of an event happening

So when i break the query into two different queries they are returning right values. If i run it as above, the count values are wrong (Date is correct though). I am not supposed to run two joins on the same table ? or count should not be there when you use join ?

Comment: You can't run SQL in a code snippet, it's only for Javascript.

Comment: When you run two joins, you get a cartesian product of both tables, and `count()` will count the rows in the product.

Comment: You may be able to solve it using `COUNT(DISTINCT map_pingpong.some_unique_column)`

Comment: Sorry for adding the code snippet.. i thought the query will be more reader friendly that way :)

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar said, you have to dissociate the resultsets to get correct counts:

```
SELECT 
    bugs.bug_id AS bug_id, 
    map_pingpong.cnt AS re_open, 
    map_closetime.mx AS closed_date
FROM bugs 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT bug_id, COUNT(bug_when) AS cnt
        FROM bugs_activity
        WHERE fieldid = 15
        GROUP BY bug_id
    ) AS map_pingpong ON map_pingpong.bug_id = bugs.bug_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ba.bug_id, MAX(ba.bug_when) AS mx
        FROM bugs_activity ba JOIN bugs ON bugs.bug_status = 'CLOSED' AND ba.bug_id = bug.bug_id AND bugs.assigned_to = 480
        WHERE ba.fieldid = 8
        GROUP BY ba.bug_id
    ) AS map_closetime ON bugs.bug_id = map_closetime.bug_id
WHERE bugs.assigned_to = 480
GROUP BY bugs.bug_id 
ORDER BY bug_id;
```

As this is correct functionally speaking, it might be a complete disaster in terms of performance so, be careful...

Comment: Thanks alot barmar and semas. I understood the issue now. I was assuming that count is applicable for the corresponding JOIN case only.